# Tile based smooth snake movement

Tags: movement, grid, timestep, allegro, snake

while making my own Snake implementation I decided to use delta time for smoothing movement on screen. The problem is that before Snake was moving fixed amount of pixels every frame, but now when mulitplying snakeSpeed by timeStep it's no longer aligned to the grid. How can I fix it?

Main game function:

```
void Run()
{
    while (!gameOver)
    {
        Time = (float)al_get_time() * 1000.0;
        timeStep = Time - lastFrameTime;

        Input();

        if (draw && al_is_event_queue_empty(eventQueue))
        {
            al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));

            UpdateSnake(&snake, timeStep, direction);
            Draw();
            Logic();

            al_flip_display();
            draw = false;
        }
    }
}
```

UpdateSnake() function (for now it's only one element moving):

```
void UpdateSnake(Snake *snake, float timeStep, Position direction)
{
    snake->animationTime += timeStep;

    float f = snake->animationTime * snakeSpeed;

    if (f >= 1.0f)
    {
        snake->animationTime = 0.0f;
        f = 1.0f;
    }

    snake->animationOrigin.x = ((int)snake->position.x / BOARD_CELL) * BOARD_CELL;
    snake->animationOrigin.y = ((int)snake->position.y / BOARD_CELL) * BOARD_CELL;

    if (direction.x == 1)
    {
        snake->animationDestination.x = snake->animationOrigin.x + BOARD_CELL;
        snake->animationDestination.y = snake->animationOrigin.y;
    }

    if (direction.x == -1)
    {
        snake->animationDestination.x = snake->animationOrigin.x - BOARD_CELL;
        snake->animationDestination.y = snake->animationOrigin.y;
    }

    if (direction.y == 1)
    {
        snake->animationDestination.x = snake->animationOrigin.x;
        snake->animationDestination.y = snake->animationOrigin.y + BOARD_CELL;
    }

    if (direction.y == -1)
    {
        snake->animationDestination.x = snake->animationOrigin.x;
        snake->animationDestination.y = snake->animationOrigin.y - BOARD_CELL;
    }

    snake->position.x = Lerp(snake->animationOrigin.x, snake->animationDestination.x, f);
    snake->position.y = Lerp(snake->animationOrigin.y, snake->animationDestination.y, f);

}
```

Comment: Linear interpolation is better than constant accumulation. Just interpolate snake's position between the cells. Misalignment comes from the floating point precision sorcery. `lerp(prev_pos, curr_pos, 1.0f/lerp_duration*lerp_time)`

Comment: @Ocelot a little more detail and that could make a good answer. ;)

Comment: @Ocelot yeah that would be great :)

Comment: your snake movement never should be bigger than a cell size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable timestep is imprecise due to the floating point arithmetics, so by constant accumulation you add up the errors as well.

To avoid this, you can define start and the end points and with the use of linear interpolation you will achieve smooth transition between them.

Here's the code solution. It requires you to extend your `snake` class with few elements:

`float anim_time;` - how much time passed since the animation start

`Position anim_origin;` - position of the previous cell

`Position anim_dest;` - position of the destination cell

```
float lerp(float a, float b, float f)
{
    return a + f * (b - a);
}

void UpdateSnake(Snake *snake, float timeStep)
{   
    snake->anim_time += timeStep;

    float f = min(anim_time*snakeSpeed, 1.0f);//min clamps interpolation factor to (-inf; 1]
    snake->position.x = lerp(snake->anim_origin.x, snake->anim_dest.x, f);
    snake->position.y = lerp(snake->anim_origin.y, snake->anim_dest.y, f);
}
```

Note that you will have to reset `anim_time` to zero and calculate start and destination points every time you move to the next cell.

Also, instead of `snake->anim_time += timeStep;` you can store animation start time and use `snake->anim_time = current_time - anim_time_start;`

Comment: Thank you for help! Didn't really know about this lerp algorithm.

Comment: @wixy0 if everything works as it should, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: of course, I'm new here so thanks for mentioning that

Comment: @wixy0 and how am I supposed to know if you implemented it right? Update your question.

Comment: @wixy0 you're supposed to reset animation time every time you finish animation.

Comment: Doesn't matter as long as your measurement is consistent - if time in seconds, then `snakeSpeed` is units per second, `animationTime` is seconds and `timeStep` is seconds. If you want to reset time automatically in `Update()`, then remove `min()` from the `f` and add a line below `if(f >= 1.0f){snake->animTime = 0.0f; f = 1.0f;}`

Comment: I'm almost there, when going right and down (x or y are raising) everything's fine but in the other directions it just goes really fast. I can't find where is the problem. I also updated my question, again :/

Comment: @wix0 check if position x and y components are signed. If you try to subtract from unsigned type it wraps.

Comment: They are signed, unfortunetaly.

Comment: It seems like this Lerp() function doesn't work backwords? I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: @wixy0 it works, inspect your code with debugger.

Comment: it was my fault, everything works now, thank you very much for your patience :)